# Sorting a 2D-Array into Ascending order

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array

- I am trying to print out the contents of an Array into Ascending order, i am also using Functions (part of a task i have been assigned) - i am fairly new to C/C++ hence if anything is a mess.
- The Sorting algorithm i have used just outputs all the numbers into a random order, any way to resolve or correct this? - Ideally this needs to output into the 2x2 grid as the Array Displays.

[Ascending Order Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgDbX.jpg)

```
include <stdio.h>/*Seperate Function for Input ArrayInt */
int main(){
int arrayHeight, array[100][2], xCoord, yCoord, i;
printf ("***** Bubble Sort ***** \n");  
printf("\n How many items of data do you wish to enter? ");
scanf("%d",&arrayHeight);
for(i=0; i<arrayHeight; i++){
    printf("Please enter in the X coordinate: ");
    scanf("%d", &xCoord);
    printf("Please enter in the Y coordinate: ");
    scanf("%d", &yCoord);
    array[i][0] = xCoord;
    array[i][1] = yCoord;
}
DisplayArray(array, arrayHeight);
BubbleSort(array, arrayHeight);
}
int DisplayArray(int array[100][2],int arrayHeight, int swap) {
/*Displaying Array elements*/
int i, j;
printf("\n The 2-D Array contains : \n");
for(i=0; i<arrayHeight; i++)
{
    printf("[%d][%d]\n\r", array[i][1], array[i][0]);
}
}  
 int BubbleSort(int array[100][2], int arrayHeight)
{   
/*Sorts the Array elements into appropriate chosen sorting order - Ascending*/
int swap, i, j, k;
for(k =0; k< arrayHeight; k++) {
            for (i = 0; i <arrayHeight; i++) {
            for (j = i+1; j < 3; ++j) {
            if (array[i][0] > array[i][-1])  {
                array[i][1] = swap;
                swap = array[i][0]; /*Array = Array Name*/
             }
         }  
     }
 }    
printf("\n Printing in Asending Order: ");
{
for (i=0; i<arrayHeight; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<arrayHeight; j++)
        {
            printf("\n [%d][%d] ", array[i][-1], array[i][1]);  
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you really mean `array[i][-1]`? If so, why?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Well i got this from an earlier work piece which i believed the code could be used in this too, what would be the correct or more useful way?

Comment: If it's not your code, I suggest you write your own, only perhaps getting some ideas from this one.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Well i am using it the code from an unrelated project. But i will take a crack at sorting it out